# Filtering on Elasticsearch Optional Fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch to query a document type, that has an *optional* location field. When searching, if that field does not exist, those results should be returned, as well as filtering on the results that do.

It seems like the OR filter in Elasticsearch does not short circuit, as this:

```
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "match_phrase_prefix": {
                "display_name": "SearchQuery"
            }
        },
    "filter": {
        "or": [
        {
            "missing": {
                "field": "location"
            }
        },
        {
            "geo_distance" : {
                "distance" : "20mi",
                "location" : {
                    "lat" : 33.47,
                    "lon" : -112.07
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Fails with "failed to find geo_point field [location]".

Is there any way to perform this (or something along the same vein) in ES?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with the same issue, I kind of just hacked around it. For any documents that were missing a "location", I added one with a lat/lon of 0/0. Then I altered my query to be:

```
"filter": {
    "or": [
        {
            "geo_distance": {
                "distance": "0.1mi",
                "location": {
                    "lat": 0,
                    "lon": 0
                 }
            }
        },
        {
            "geo_distance": {
                "distance": "30mi",
                "location": {
                    "lat": [lat variable],
                    "lon": [lon variable]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why yours isn't working but I've used the [bool filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html#bool-filter) with great success in the past. The `should` option is essentially an `or` and makes sure at least one is true. Give it a try and comment on my answer if it still doesn't work. Also double check I copied your query terms properly :)

```
{
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "match_phrase_prefix": {
                "display_name": "SearchQuery"
            }
        },
        "filter" : {
            "bool" : {
                "should" : [
                    {
                        "missing": { "field": "location" }
                    },
                    {
                        "geo_distance" : {
                            "distance" : "20mi",
                            "location" : {
                                "lat" : 33.47,
                                "lon" : -112.07
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that still gives me the same error. It seems like it's trying to execute the second clause even though the first one matches.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_dealing_with_null_values.html#_missing_query